# How to swap more than 20 images when click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set of images which is nearly(30) in a folder and i want to swap the images when i click the images one by one it has to disappear and show another image in the same place
    I have written a Jquery click function for it work but due to my script is very long it provides a slow process in swapping the images and it Kill's the script can anyone help me  to simplify this code. 
                    thanks in advance

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".swap").click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture2.bmp");
      $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture3.png");
      $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture4.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture5.bmp");
      $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture6.bmp");
      $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture7.bmp");
      $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture8.bmp");
      $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture9.bmp");
      $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture10.bmp");
      $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture11.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture12.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture13.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture14.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture15.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture16.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture17.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture18.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture19.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture20.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture21.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture22.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture22.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture23bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture24.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture25.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture26.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture27.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture28.bmp");
   $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","./images/picture29.bmp");
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
 });
 });
 });    
 });
 });
 });
    });
    });
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<img src="./images/Picture1.bmp" class="swap">
</div>
```

Comment: Store the images inside an array and increment the index to show on each click

Comment: You are binding a new click event every time you click so by the you finish, you have 29 click events running that bind even more clicks so you probably have hundreds of events running on a single click - that is the cause of your js being so slow

Comment: Thats funny ... if you look at this code and the one in the answers below you can see what big of a journey a developer can make over the years :D

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
var max = 30;    
var current = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".swap").click(function(){
        current++;
        $(this).attr("src","./images/picture"+current+".bmp");
        if (current == max) current = 0;
    });
});
```

this would work if your images are in fact named as in example you provided. Alternatively you can also store image names in table and update full image using `current` as table index.

And of course I assumed that it should return to picture1.bmp after 30. You could also make check before switching src and simply return.

Answer (score 2):

Simply do with `c++` increment the value on each click  .Restrict with if `less 30` use with [`Ternary operator`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiS5bG_3pfUAhVBpo8KHUjfD8IQFghcMAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FConditional_Operator&usg=AFQjCNEyfU4zvkUJSNIonRwYQ86E1fetTg&sig2=d1StxKp-2KPtYi5V_yrSLw)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var c=2;
  $(".swap").click(function() {
  c = c<30 ? c : 2; //allow only less then 30 else  reset to 2
    $(this).attr("src", "./images/picture"+(c++)+".bmp");
    console.log($(this).attr("src"))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="./images/Picture1.bmp" class="swap">
</div>
```

Comment: @Deus777 yes .i was changed from last edit see my updated edit

Comment: Yes, I've noticed :)